# How to print binary file

Tags: c++, file

I wanted to create a binary file with integers from 0 to 10 in it. After that i wanted to double every one of them and to print them out. When I run it, nothing is being printed.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream binfile("Numbers.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++)
        binfile.write((char*)&i, sizeof(i));
    binfile.flush();
    int number;
    while(binfile.read((char*)&number, sizeof(number)))
    {
        number*=2;
        binfile.seekp(binfile.tellg()-sizeof(number));
        binfile.write((char*)&number, sizeof(number));
        binfile.flush();
    }
    binfile.seekg(0);
    while(binfile.read((char*)&number, sizeof(number)))
        cout<<number;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using the same stream object for input and output is tricky. Start out by using two separate stream objects, one to write the file and one to read it. After you've got that working you can try using the same object for both.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` condition is never met. Your first (and only) read attempt return `0` - which is why nothing is printed.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fix it, I really don't know how to that myself.

Comment: @Vito -- begin by removing that first `while` loop. Then see if you can get the code working. You're trying to do too many things at once.

Answer (score 0):

after the first loop, you have to seek the "get" pointer to 0th position for overwriting the numbers in subsequent "while" loop 
the second loop terminates because eofbit of the binfile get set, all the following input-output operations will get invalidated, so we have to clear the eofbit to restart the operations

working code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>        

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream binfile("Numbers.dat", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    for(int i=0; i<=10; i++) // 1st loop
        binfile.write((char*)&i, sizeof(i));
    binfile.flush();
    binfile.seekg(0);
    int number;
    while(binfile.read((char*)&number, sizeof(number))) // 2nd loop
    {
        number*=2;
        binfile.seekp(binfile.tellg()-sizeof(number));
        binfile.write((char*)&number, sizeof(number));
        binfile.flush();
    }
    binfile.clear();
    binfile.seekg(0);
    while(binfile.read((char*)&number, sizeof(number))) // 3rd loop
        cout<<number << " ";
    return 0;
}
```